# Bower different dependencies using different jquery versions

Tags: jquery, bower

As the title says I have dependencies which have different versions of jquery. How can I resolve this? Since only one version is in jquery/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0):

You can specify jQuery Versions:

```
$ bower install jquery#1.11.1  --save
```

So in `package.json` you might have something like:

```
"dependencies": {
    "jquery": "2.0.0",
    "jquery-1.9.1": "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"
}
```

You can specify `<`, `>` and `~` to specify, less than, greater than and starting with.

```
$ bower install "jquery#<2.0 >1.10"
```

Comment: I know, but then I'd have to manually change those version every time the library is updated.

Comment: Well based on the plugins, you can specify `>` and `<` for the plugins. Then it will pull the latest within the threshold you have supplied.
`$ bower install "jquery#<2.0 >1.10"`

Comment: And `~` to say, starting with. `~1.11` for example would include all 1.11.x versions.